# DensityPlot and KroneckerDelta

Tags: plotting

I have the following DensityPlot:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, {y, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now I want to see only the values of density along the function "y = 1/2 (ArcCos[1 - Cos[2 x]])". I had the idea to use a KroneckerDelta as following but it does not work !

```
X[x_, y_] = KroneckerDelta[1/2 (ArcCos[1 - Cos[2 x]]), y]

DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y]*X[x, y], {x, -Pi/4, Pi/4}, {y, -Pi/4, Pi/4},ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Any idea why this is not working and how to rectify ?

Thank you for your time !

Geoff

Comment: `DensityPlot` is not meant to be used for drawing curves.

Comment: Since `KroneckerDelta` is in effect "infinitely thin," `DensityPlot` can't locate where it is nonzero.

Comment: Ok I understand the problem !

Answer (score 3):

If you want a curve whose shape is determined by `y = 1/2 (ArcCos[1 - Cos[2 x]])` and whose color is determined by `Sin[x] Sin[y]`, you may use

```
Plot[1/2 (ArcCos[1 - Cos[2 x]]), {x, -\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["SunsetColors"][Sin[x] Sin[y]]]]
```

[image]